# Finding the z value

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

So I am new to normal distribution, I need help on understanding on how to calculate it's z-value

Question : What is the z value which has 87.49% of the area below it?

Comment: It is not easy to _calculate_ probabilities associated with the normal distribution. The answer to your question is best found by searching a table of the CDF (which typically lists the values $P\{Z \leq z\}$ for $0 \leq z \leq 3.5$) to see which $z$ is listed for $0.8749$

Comment: oh okay, thanks you, it's much clearer now :)

Answer (score 1):

The $z$-value for a specific probability $0\leq p \leq 1$ is the value of $z$ for which:

$$\Phi(z)=p$$

In this case you are required to use the inverse normal CDF function $\Phi^{-1}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ to find:

$$z=\Phi^{-1}(0.8749)$$

You can use tables or other tools to evaluate this. Using Mathematica and the command `InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0,1], 0.8749]`, I get $z\approx 1.14986$.